# Check programmatically if open WLAN network is really open

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread, wifi

there are two kinds of open (unencrypted) WLAN networks: one that is really open and provides IP and network access after connecting to it, and one where additional authentication is necessary after connection to it (typically via a webpage where some special credentials have to be entered that belong to the provider of this service).

Is it possible to find out what kind of "open" network is available *before* connecting to it? Possibly somehow via the ScanResult objects that are returned as result to WiFiManager.startScan()?

Thanks!

Comment: please read the [official document] (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/ScanResult.html)  it help you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to find out what kind of "open" network is available before connecting to it?

In short, no. The Android `WifiManager` (and, indeed, any computers' networking drivers / stack) are only concerned with low level communications. Looking at the OSI Model, primarily the Physical level, Data Link level and the Network level.

WLAN hardware, drivers etc obviously have extra concerns which include scanning for available APs and verifying whether they offer 'open' access or require authentication although in the latter case it is only concerned with WEP/WPA style authentication and doesn't consider any higher level of control / security at the Transport layer, Session layer etc

The sort of authentication via web pages which you describe is often a requirement in pubs, cafes, hotels etc where the WLAN is effectively 'ring-fenced' and all HTTP traffic has to go through what is effectively an HTTP proxy server (which possibly also imposes content-screening / blockng). In the case of this sort of WLAN service, usually only web traffic is allowed - for instance attempting to connect to the outside world with any other protocol than HTTP/HTTPS will be prevented.

Consequently, any WLAN (or even LAN) client hardware, drivers, stacks has no way of discovering what is/isn't allowed or required when attempting to connect to remote / external sites and services.